# Add meta tag og:title with superscript ® for multiple social network (Mac, Window)

Tags: html, meta-tags, superscript

I just want add title on share link social network with superscript ®. (Facebook, Twitter, Line, ....) Facebook can show on chrome Mac but not show on IE Window. I check with https://metatags.io/ Twitter show correct, Facebook is not. Anyone know how we do it for multiple social network both Mac and Window?

something like that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- After many time searching I find out each browse uses its own font so that R can not being showed the same on all of them.
- So we don't have any way to do it for now.